# Как сделать такой Range Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно сделать такой слайдер? второй день голову ломаю, помогите плиз, мб есть готовые плагины какие-то. Ковырял `jqueryUI` и `noUiSlider` но так и не победил их

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не смотря на громоздкость и запутанность кода (обусловлено попыткой максимально повторить дизайн нативными средствами), думаю, что это максимально упрощено и минимизировано:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oSliderTrack = document.querySelector('.slider_track');
  var oSliderThumb = document.querySelector('.slider_thumb');

  function fDotsShow(nDots) {
    document.querySelector('.slider_dots').innerHTML = '⚫' + ' ⚫'.repeat(nDots) + '<span style="color:#333;">' + ' ⚪'.repeat(30 - nDots) + '</span>';
  }

  function fThumbMove(v) {
    let nShiftX = (isNaN(v)) ? v.pageX : v;
    if (nShiftX > oSliderTrack.offsetLeft && nShiftX < oSliderTrack.offsetLeft + oSliderTrack.clientWidth) {
      oSliderThumb.style.left = nShiftX - oSliderTrack.offsetLeft - oSliderThumb.clientWidth / 2 + 'px';
      fDotsShow(Math.floor((oSliderThumb.offsetLeft + 11) / (oSliderTrack.clientWidth / 30.3)));
      document.querySelector('.slider_summ').innerHTML = 900000 + (oSliderThumb.offsetLeft + 11) * 2100 + ' <span class="rub">Р</span>';
    }
  }

  function fThumbReset() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', fThumbMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', fThumbReset);
  }

  oSliderThumb.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', fThumbMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', fThumbReset);
  });
  document.querySelector('.slider_btn.dec').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fThumbMove(oSliderThumb.offsetLeft + oSliderTrack.offsetLeft + 11);
  });
  document.querySelector('.slider_btn.inc').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fThumbMove(oSliderThumb.offsetLeft + oSliderTrack.offsetLeft + 13);
  });
  fDotsShow(0);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fef7ef;
}

p {
  font: bold 1em Arial;
  text-align: center;
  margin: .5em auto;
}

.slider_summ {
  font: bold 2em Arial;
  color: #f87f22;
}

.rub {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.25em;
  width: 0.4em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f87f22;
}

.slider_block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 600px;
  font: .5em Arial;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.slider_btn {
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
}

.slider_btn:hover {
  filter: invert(75%);
}

.slider_track {
  position: relative;
  height: 7px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 14px;
}

.slider_dots {
  line-height: 8px;
  color: #f87f22;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

.slider_thumb {
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 24px;
  top: 27px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #f87f22;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.slider_thumb::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 11px;
  width: 22px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #f87f22;
  border-top: 0;
}

.slider_thumb::after {
  content: '≡';
  position: absolute;
  height: 23px;
  width: 20px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  color: rgb(249, 160, 95);
  font: 4em Arial;
}
```

```html
<p>Стоимость автомобиля</p>
<p class="slider_summ">900000 <span class="rub">Р</span></p>
<div class="slider_block">
  <div class="slider_btn dec">◄</div>
  <div class="slider_track">
    <div class="slider_dots"></div>
    <div class="slider_thumb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_btn inc">►</div>
</div>
```

PS На кроссбраузерность не проверял. Работает в Win7+Chrome70.